# My simple FK constraints appear to have been ignored. How?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, foreign-key

I have two tables, `device` and `platform` where `device.platform_id` enforces the following constraint:

```
Foreign-key constraints:
    "device_platform_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (platform_id) REFERENCES platform(id)
```

It has been this way since the table was first created.

And yet:

```
select count(*) from device 
where device.platform_id 
not in (select distinct p.id from platform p);
 count 
-------
   210
```

I discovered the inconsistency while testing a backup (insert or update failed because it violates foreign key constraint).

We don't have any application logic that [does something](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4EA2057F.3000002@ringerc.id.au) like `ALTER TABLE … DISABLE TRIGGER` while deferring constraint validation within a transaction.

How could my database enter this state?

The only thing that comes to mind is a bad dump/restore that may have temporarily disabled triggers and imported constraint-violating data at some point in the past.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe they were added before the FKEY was created and the FKEY was created in a NOT VALID state?

Comment: @mustaccio Indeed, but I linked the only thread I could find for "How to temporarily globally ignore constraints" for good measure.

Comment: Does `device` have an `id` column as well? If yes use a fully qualified column name in the sub-select `not in (select p.id from platform p)` (the distinct is useless in the sub-select)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It does: the fully-qualified schema names were used to *produce* the example output, but then simplified when pasting into the question. I'll edit it to avoid confusion.

Comment: @mustaccio that's technically not true, there are triggers behind FKs.  One can find them using `pg_trigger` and `pg_constraint` (some clients list them, too).

Comment: @msanford Could you please post the table definitions and some example rows violating the FK?

Comment: If the table has a serial column or some `created_at` timestamp column, you could check whether the offending rows are clustered together and if they are the latest added rows or were added back in time. If (for example) all the offending rows have timestamps after `'2015-12-20'` and you had a restore about that day, it would be a serious clue.